# Alterar vírgula de altura e largura com mascára

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mask

Tenho um código que calcula a quantidade de rolos necessária de acordo com a largura e altura da parede da pessoa. Atualmente o código para a máscara da virgula é este:

```
        $('.virgula').mask('####00,00', {reverse: true});

        $("#altura").focusout(function (){
            try{
                var altura = parseFloat( $("#altura").val().replace(',','.') );
                var largura = parseFloat( $("#largura").val().replace(',','.') );
                var divisor = 1.20;
                var resultado = largura / divisor;
```

Ou seja, quando a pessoa digita "1" e "5" o número aparece como 15 metros e só depois que ela digita o "0" é que aparece 1,50 metros.

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade do número aparecer como "1,5" com dois dígitos, como se a máscara fosse "##0,0" e depois de dois digitos ela volta para a máscara "####00,00". Já tentei alguns IFs e nada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trocar a máscara `onKeyUp`, contando os caracteres que existem no input:

```js
$('.virgula').mask('#####0,0', {reverse: true});

$('.virgula').on('keyup', function() {
  if( $(this).val().length > 3 ) {
      mascara = '####00,00';
  } else {
    mascara = '####0,0';
  }
  
  $('.virgula').mask( mascara, { reverse: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="valor" class="virgula" />
```